# How to export data frame back to the original csv file that I imported it from?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a list of DataFrames by the name of "dfs" which has 139 DataFrames. I originally imported csv files to python and have deleted first few rows from each data frame. Now I wish to save these new files back in their original positions. How can I do that. My new data is saved in another list named final. Also please tell me if I can make my code more efficient as I am a new to python.

```py
dfs = [pd.read_csv(filename) for filename in filenames]
final=[]
for i in range(139):    
    a= dfs[i].iloc[604:,]
    final.append(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I've understood it correctly, if you want to write df to csv to the same as when you made df but this time opposite way.

```
for df, filename in zip(final, filenames):
    path = f'{filename}.csv'
    df.to_csv(path)
```

Comment: All I had to do was open each of 139 csv files manually and delete the first 603 rows. But instead I'm trying to make a code do that for me through python. Firstly, I imported all 139 files from csv to python using 'pd.read_csv'. Then I deleted first 603 rows from each csv file using for loop. After that I saved the new dataFrame list by the name 'final'. in python. **Now I want these data frames to replace the csv files that I originally had in my computer.** bold part is where I'm having problems

Comment: why not just name them same as ur original csv files?

Comment: yes. I wanna name them same as my original csv file but I dont know how to do that. I'm just stuck here. All I want to do is that save all the data frames that are in final to the respective csv files that I got the data for dfs

Comment: @AliInayat I've edited my answer, one way is to overwrite csv. If you want to delete files after you read it then write new ones you use use `os` module in python.